# Bootstrap navbar creating two rows at certain widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the latest Boostrap (v3) to create a test environment.
I have when the window is resized to around 750px the navbar collapses into two rows rather than hiding and displaying the menu toggle.

This behaviour is only between around 600 - 750px

Check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uToYapO/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

CSS

change width from 750px to auto

```
@media (min-width: 768px)

  .container {
  width: auto;
  }
```

Comment: the problem is still persistent with suggestion

Comment: Are you sure you applied changes correctly? When I added width:auto inline it works http://jsbin.com/uToYapO/2

Comment: Yep, just used your link and resized the window http://i39.tinypic.com/25zhzb8.png

Comment: I see... it works fine on mine. Can you go to that link again, I know layout is "bit" broken now but just want to check is it collapses into two rows again. http://jsbin.com/uToYapO/2

Comment: It looks like that link works fine, even the previous link works now too.. (maybe it was cached). Would there be a way to keep the width that its set to as that was the whole purpose of the container.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uToYapO/4 if nav in this one wont collapse we will be able to fix container

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46090/discussion-between-amaro-and-imran)